# 'Confess to object' vs 'Confess object'

Tags: verbs

> - She confessed the murder.
> - She confessed to the murder.

What is the difference in the meaning between both sentences? If there is not any difference, why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***she confessed the murder*** is not a common phrasing, but you will find examples of it here and there, especially if crime fiction is your thing. However, when say "confess", we're usually thinking of the complete expression which is [***to confess to something***](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/confess+to+(someone+or+something)). So, ***she confessed to the murder*** is fine. You could also say ***I confess I did it***. Here, however, ***I confess*** is used to mean I admit that I did it and now feel guilty because of that.

Comment: "Confess" can take a direct object, e.g. "He confessed his sins".

Comment: Sure it can, but not in the context where we're talking about murder.

Comment: There are plenty of references to "confess the murder" Here's just one [link](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=1oS5dJVrwFkC&pg=PT493&lpg=PT493&dq=He+%22confessed+the+murder%22.&source=bl&ots=D5u0RtAYZY&sig=Pb4y2pzZiSmhWYqFaZU9ijDO5u8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjy9rC61sLXAhWoAMAKHf_iAHwQ6AEIOjAC#v=onepage&q=He%20%22confessed%20the%20murder%22.&f=false)

Comment: Can you find me a passage from a news article where they say that somebody confessed the murder?

Comment: [link](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-3623493/Plenty-fish-killer-Carl-Langdell-jailed-life-murder-Katie-Locke.html)

Comment: Then, I guess I'm wrong. I just don't think I've ever heard that kind of usage of confess.

Comment: @BillJ - That's one link, and [here are a bunch of others](https://www.google.com/search?q="confessed+the+murder"&safe=off&source=lnms&tbm=nws&start=14)